# String name of a other string name

Tags: c#

I need to set a new string and that the user need to set this new string name
for example:

```
int input = 0;
            while (input != -1)
            {
                input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                int count = 0;
                count ++;
                int ("the " count)= intput;
            }
```

Comment: User will have to input values forever

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I don't know where to begin.  The count variable that is set to 0 then to 1 every iteration or the declaration of a string as a variable name being assigned the value of intput. Also, what in the world is this supposed to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, that is, waht do ypu need:

```
        int input = 0;
        var inputs = new List<int>();
        while (input != -1)
        {
            input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            int count = 0;
            count++;
            inputs.Add(input);
        }

        var result = inputs.Select((j, i) => Tuple.Create("The " + i, j)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks you help me a lot too

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a "dynamic *variable*", you want a *dictionary*.  Something like this:

```
Dictionary<int, int> values = new Dictionary<int, int>();
int count = 0;
int input = 0;
while (input != -1)
{
    input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    count++;
    values.Add(count, input);
}
```

You can do your `"the"` part in some output if you need to, but the values being stored in this case appear to be just `int` values anyway.  If you want to get creative you can wrap some data types in a custom class and output formatted strings from that class easily enough.

Another change to note above is moving the declaration of `count` outside of the loop, otherwise it's *always* going to be 1.

Basically, just about any time you find yourself wanting a dynamic variable name following some pattern, what you actually want is a collection of some kind.  Maybe a dictionary, maybe a list, maybe something else, etc.

Comment: Thanks you help me a lot